# Как создавать папку в папке

Tags: java

Хотел бы узнать, как можно создать папку в папке, вызывая одну функцию

```
functionCreate(nameOfFile);
```

created Folder

```
functionCreate(nameOfFile);
```

created Folder/Folder1

```
functionCreate(nameOfFile);
```

created Folder/Folder1/Folder2

Comment: а что у вас не получилось? где ваш кусочек кода?

Comment: В классе `File` есть метод `mkdirs`, который делает то, что вам нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько способов:

1. `Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("./directory/sub_directory"))`
2. `new File("./directory/sub_directory").mkdirs()`

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
File file = new File("*путь*");
file.mkdir();
```